# Найти половины слов/словосочетаний, которые состоят из одинаковых частей? Регулярные выражения

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

**Важно** использовать одну нумерованную группу или не использовать их совсем.

*Пример данных:*
мама папа дядя йойо кокос балалайка чуть-чуть

*Правильный ответ:*
ма па дя йо чуть

Мои попытки: 
`\b([\w]{2})\1\b|\b(?:[\w]{4}(?=-))\b` - находит первую группу, но не захватывает "чуть". Проверил, то что после `| \b(?:[\w]{4}(?=-))\b` - "чуть" находит.

Далее решил попробовать совсем не использовать нумерованные группы. Написал вот это `'\b(?:[\w]{2})\b|\b(?:[\w]{4}(?=-))\b'` осталось только чуть. По-видимому тут не обойтись без нумерованной группы для слов из 4 букв (возможно, я не прав). Прошу помощи :)

Comment: `\b(.+?)-?\1\b` - https://regex101.com/r/HhrThc/1

Comment: Не могли бы объяснить, как работает здесь '?'

Comment: `?` обозначает 0 или 1 вхождение

Comment: Ознакомьтесь с рекомендациями по вопросам в описании тэга "регулярные выражения". Всегда надо указывать язык реализации.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\b(\w+)-?\1\b
```

Без обратной ссылки, а значит и сохраняющих групп, регулярное выражение, решающее данную задачу, написать невозможно.

Comment: Не могли бы объяснить, как работает здесь '?'

Comment: @Whoops здесь `?` обозначает что дефис может быть, а может и не быть.